# What is the LaTeX code for the symbol denoting a collection of nonempty sets that forms a partition of a set?

Tags: math-fonts

Page 1161 of "Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest and Clifford Stein. Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition. MIT Press, 2009" says

[image]

What is the LaTeX code for the symbol

[image]

that denotes a collection of nonempty sets that forms a partition of a set?

Comment: The symbol is just a script style capital S; see my comment to @Mico's answer.

Comment: Apparently the publisher uses MathTimePro and that happens to be the glyph used for `\mathcal{S}`. It's not a particular symbol, just a script S.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To reproduce the symbol in question *exactly*, you will need to have access to the  [MathTime II Professional](https://www.pctex.com/68MTPro2Fonts.html) font package, a commercial Times Roman clone math font. It is not free of charge; however, it's not superexpensive either.

If the following test document compiles successfully on your system, you already have the font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr=mt]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathscr{S}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to spend the money on a math font package for just one symbol, you could consider replacing `\usepackage[scr=mt]{mathalfa}` with `\usepackage{stix2}` -- another Times Roman clone math font package.

Comment: I would add the more basic information that this is just a script capital letter S, so if the OP is not worried about imitating the particular font they can just use `\mathcal{S}`, or `\mathscr{S}` with any appropriate package.